Fermat's last Theorem and elliptic curve cryptography
AFAIR, elliptic curve cryptography became popular soon after Fermat's last Theorem had been proven. Is it just a coincidence, or some important cryptographic properties of elliptic curves follow from the Fermat's statement?

There is no relationship between the two.
FLT is about homogeneous equations of the form $x^n+y^n=z^n$ over the integers and states that no integer solution exists when $n\geq 3.$ Yes it is stated in wikipedia that

Wiles proved the modularity theorem for semistable elliptic curves, from which Fermat’s last theorem follows using proof by contradiction

however these are elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}.$
The elliptic curves used in Elliptic Curve cryptography are over finite fields, either $GF(p)$ (integers modulo a prime) or some extension field of $GF(p).$ A very different (and finite) object.

Because DLog is easy to solve.

I don't think there is any connection and the temporal link is weak. First, Fermat's last theorem was proven in 1994. Second, elliptic curve cryptography was proposed in 1985, so about 10 years before and according to wikipedia became widespread around 2004/ 2005, so around 10 years after Wiles proof.
